# Question in deriving Ito's Isometry

Tags: stochastic-processes

I am trying to wrap my head around stochastic integrals, and I am having trouble understanding the proof of Ito's Isometry,
$$
I^2 = \sum_{j=0}^k \Delta^2(t_j)D^2_j + 2\sum_{0 \leq i < j \leq k} \Delta(t_i)\Delta(t_j)D_iD_j
$$
where $D_j = W(t_{j+1}) - W(t_j)$.

This is from Shreve's book, and I am having a hard time why the second term goes to zero. In particular, I am having a hard time understanding why $\mathbb{E}[D_j] = 0$.

The book proves this by introducing $\cal{F}(t_j)$ and that $\Delta(t_i)\Delta(t_j)D_i$ is $\cal{F}(t_j)$-measurable. But since there are no filtrations in the formula for Ito's Isometry, I find it hard to understand why we need to introduce $\sigma$-algebra here.

Comment: Because you can condition and use the independent increment property.